# Qt Quick Controls 2 and Windows Phone 10

Tags: qt, qtquickcontrols2

I've created a new Qt Quick Controls 2 project.
Built it using Qt 5.7.0 for Universal Windows Platform armv7 kit. 
Ran on my Windows Phone (Lumia 650).
All I see is a blank black screen.
Am I doing something wrong? 
I've also tried Qt Widgets projects: works, but controls are not usable due to scale problems.

Application output:

```
winrtrunner --device 0 --start --stop --install --wait 0 C:/Users/user/Documents/build-untitled1-Qt_5_7_0_for_Universal_Windows_Platform_armv7-Release/release/untitled1.exe
qt.winrtrunner: Using the AppxPhone profile.
qt.winrtrunner: No mapping file exists. Only recognized files will be packaged.
qt.winrtrunner: App started with process ID 4788
```

Comment: Any relevant debug output? Does the app run with a desktop kit?

Comment: Added the output. Yes, the app runs fine with the VC2015 32bit desktop kit.

Comment: No errors from the QML engine? I would assume that it's a deployment issue ie. some QML module is missing from the application package, but it's hard to tell without any errors. :) Is it possible to introspect the contents of the application package that gets deployed on the phone?

Comment: I was browsing the issue tracker and stumbled upon [this comment](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52926?focusedCommentId=318370&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-318370): "Some more information about the WinRT related stuff: ... `CONFIG+=windeployqt` ... is needed for also deploying the right QML modules for the application." - does adding that config to the .pro file help?

Comment: Here is the unpacked appx package with the all contents: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3u05tlcjpwwfja/appx-unpacked.zip?dl=0

Comment: windeployqt did not help..

Comment: The package structure looks a bit strange, but a quick look suggests that despite some duplicates, the dependencies are there in the package at least. I would expect all QML stuff to be in a "qml" folder, but perhaps this is how it's supposed to be on Windows Phone. I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Any output if you run the app with `QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1` environment variable set?

Comment: Got the same output..

Comment: Created a bug report here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55578

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Qt. Fixed in 5.7.1 version released recently.